# PyQT treewidgets with different context menu options

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

i have 2 treewidgets placed in a frame in mainwindow. how can i have 2 different set of context menu options for the 2 treewidgets? i need individual set of right click options for the treewidgets.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `QWidget` has a `contextMenuPolicy` property which defines what to do when context menu is requested. A simpliest way to do what you need is like this:

1. Create `QAction` objects that call methods you want.
2. Add these actions to your tree widgets using `widget.addAction()`
3. Call `widget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)`

That's it. Context menu for the widget will contain actions you added.

Comment: Thanks.. can i have the context menu for the entries in the tree widget, instead of having it for the entire widget.?

Comment: i dont want context menu over empty spaces. i need it for the entries in the widget. when the menu is chosen i wanna read the list item selected(which i wil check using checkstate as the list item has checkbox).

Comment: Not sure about it. The entries are QTreeWidgetItem, and this class is not a widget, so it does not have built in methods for working with context menu.